# redirect any results in command prompt to richtext box

Tags: c#

I need to redirect any results in command prompt to richtext box. Can any one provide me the necessary steps. This is how i start my command prompt.

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo
                {
                    FileName = "cmd",
                    Arguments = @"/k ""C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\bin\vcvars32.bat""",
                };
                Process.Start(psi);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
        var process = new Process
        {
            StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/C dir c:")
            {
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                UseShellExecute = false,
            }
        };
        process.Start();
        string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        process.WaitForExit();
        Console.WriteLine(output);
```

EDIT: Then you can try this

```
        var process = new Process
        {
            StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe")
            {
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                RedirectStandardInput = true,
                UseShellExecute = false,
            }
        };
        process.Start();

        // Discard "Microsoft windows all rights reserved etc.
        while (process.StandardOutput.ReadLine() != "") ;
        // Run command
        process.StandardInput.WriteLine("dir c:");
        // Skip command entered
        process.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
        // And exit
        process.StandardInput.WriteLine("exit");
        process.WaitForExit();
        string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        Console.WriteLine(output);
```

Comment: Great work... Thanks. But this will show the cmd and disappear. I need to hold cmd until i execute command. Than that result need to rederect to richtext box

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to redirect the stdout stream from the Process. I don't remember the exact properties and methods involved, but take a look through the MSDN documentation on `Process`.

Comment: I check it, but i unable to get it. Can you please provide me some sample code